# How to find cells of different shapes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

Ability to find a clear number of cells in the embryo.

[Single cell picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZFPm.jpg)

[Double cell picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqra2.jpg)

It has different shapes. I want to take out the cells in the embryo and find out the shape and number of the cells. How can I do this? Can this be done using morphological operations or any function on Matlab? I use the Regionprops function to detect each individual shape, and then I can operate on each region separately.

Thanks very much

Comment: Stackoverflow is used to ask specific question about programming. If you're looking for a method you should read the scientific literature.

Comment: The [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) may be an appropriate place to ask about choice of computer vision methods prior to having any programming problem implementing such methods to ask about here.

Comment: As mentioned above, SO is about code. However, DIC and phase images are hard to segment accurately, you can try watershed and convexhull to get approximate shape.